# MAMP fresh install cannot access phpmyadmin

Tags: mamp

I'm using MAMP to set up a magenta installation.  But after a fresh install of MAMP, I wanted to set up the db and it's giving me this error:

MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings. 
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I've been researching for over an hour and everything I find doesn't help.  I never changed the default password for mysql and I'm able to log in using the command line and -uroot -proot.  I also tried changing the password and it didn't make any difference.

OSX 10.11.0
MAMP 3.5.1
PHP 7.0.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your PHP version in MAMP is 5.6.10.

I've been having the exact same problem and just switched the PHP prefs from 7.0.8 to 5.6.10, restarted the servers and I can get into phpMyAdmin now.

It was driving my bonkers as well.

Comment: What is the reason of it ? How do you solve it ? Can you please explain if you know ?